# How do I access the checkbox field column value as a PHP array?

Tags: modules, checkboxes

I have a checkbox field for dining cuisine types and I see that the checked options are stored as a JSON-encoded array in the content table. If I have an element that uses this field, is there a way I can just get that JSON-encoded value as an array in PHP? Any time I try to get the value of the field, I'm getting the entire MultiOptionsFieldData object which isn't desired in this case. I just want that array of checked values that's stored in the corresponding content table column.

[image]

I don't want to write any loops. I just want access to that actual column value from my element in PHP.

I don't want to write any additional queries to get that column value either. Surely, there must be a way to get the actual field value for checkbox fields. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiOptionsFieldData` extends PHP's [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class.

You could get the values from it by casting it to an array like so:

```
$results = (array)$mofd;
```

That would give you an array of `OptionData` classes.  If you really didn't want to loop through them, you could do something like:

```
$func = static function($ofd) {
    return $ofd->value;
};

$results = array_map($func, (array)$mofd);
```

Comment: Yeah, getting the array of OptionData instances was as close as I got but I was hoping for just the array of string values. Thanks, Brad. I think a method to obtain the raw value on the MultiOptionsFieldData class might be helpful in situations like this. Maybe something like:

$entry->getFieldValue('diningCuisine')->rawValue()

Answer (score 1):

Another option for getting the string values as an array after typecasting the `MultiOptionsFieldData` object as an array:

```
$values = ArrayHelper::getColumn(ArrayHelper::toArray( (array) $entry->getFieldValue('diningCuisine') ), 'value');
```